# Python equality check

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
chars=input()
a=([int(x.strip()) for x in chars.split(',')])
b=len(a)
count=1
result=0
max=0
for i in range(b-1):
    for j in range(i,b):
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            print(a[i])
            count=count+1
    result=result+(a[i]*count)
    count=0
```

In the above code I check condition if `a[i]==a[j]` is true and I am printing the result if they are equal.

But I get something wrong output.

Given the input

```
-9,3,0,20,-10,-11,11
```

The above prints

```
-9
3
0
20
-10
-11
```

There are no equal values in the input, why are they all printed?

Answer (score 3):

You always have one iteration per iteration over `range(i, b)`, where `i == j`. You started your inner loop *at* `i` after all, so *of course* `a[i] == a[j]` is going to be true, they are *the same index in your list*.

Start your inner loop at `i + 1` instead:

```
for i in range(b-1):
    for j in range(i + 1, b):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chars=input()
a=chars # input() Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))
b=len(a)
count=1
result=0
max=0
for i in range(b-1):
    for j in range(i+1,b): # start from  i + 1
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            print(a[i])
            count=count+1
    result=result+(a[i]*count)
    count=0
```